# JHipster - "Problem with Filer: Attempt to recreate a file for type" during compileJava task

Tags: jhipster

1. I generated a JHipster app.
2. Launched the `bootRun`  command.
3. Regenerated a couple of entities with the `jhipster-jdl` (removed some required fields).
4. The application worked fine.
5. Dropped the DB with the `clean` command to get a fresh DB.

Now I get following error when I launch the bootRun command:

```
2021-10-10T14:28:05.607+0200 [ERROR] [system.err] Note: Hibernate JPA 2 Static-Metamodel Generator 5.4.32.Final
2021-10-10T14:28:05.608+0200 [ERROR] [system.err] error: Problem with Filer: Attempt to recreate a file for type com.testapp.domain.Note_
2021-10-10T14:28:05.608+0200 [ERROR] [system.err] error: Problem with Filer: Attempt to recreate a file for type com.testapp.domain.ApplicationUser_
2021-10-10T14:28:05.609+0200 [ERROR] [system.err] error: Problem with Filer: Attempt to recreate a file for type com.testapp.domain.Authority_
2021-10-10T14:28:05.609+0200 [ERROR] [system.err] error: Problem with Filer: Attempt to recreate a file for type com.testapp.domain.User_
2021-10-10T14:28:05.609+0200 [ERROR] [system.err] error: Problem with Filer: Attempt to recreate a file for type com.testapp.domain.AbstractAuditingEntity_
2021-10-10T14:28:05.609+0200 [ERROR] [system.err] error: Problem with Filer: Attempt to recreate a file for type com.testapp.domain.Tag_
2021-10-10T14:28:05.702+0200 [ERROR] [system.err] 6 errors
```

And the server won't start anymore.

Comment: Hello, I did run in the same issue. Did you found out what the issue was?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do a clean before. Sometimes gradle seems to consider inputs as changed although they have most likely not. Which gradle version are you using?